# jQuery to toggle rows when one of it's cell is clicked

Tags: jquery

I've a table in which first `<td>` in every row is clickable. When it is clicked it should expand - display some data in a `<div>`and when clicked again the `<div>` must be hidden. So far I've tried [this](http://jsfiddle.net/0yjar83e/) but I'm not able to hide it back. Plz provide your suggestions based on the sample fiddle attached.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
$('#tbdyId').on('click', 'a', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var $currentRow = $(this).closest("tr");
    console.log($currentRow);
    var $sib = $currentRow.next().children().find('div');
    console.log("sib: ");
    console.log($sib);
    if ($sib.is('.expanded')) {
       $sib.closest('tr').toggle();
    } else {
        var newRow = $currentRow.after("<tr><td colspan='5'>" +
            "<div align='center' class='expanded'> <table border='0'>" +
            "<tr><td>  some data </td></tr></table></div>" +
            "</td></tr>");
    } 
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/0yjar83e/2/)